# Pharse First Column of a text file db into php or JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, text-files

So I am starting to learn things about JSON.

What I am trying to do is pharse the first column (id) of this txt file

http://www.ufo-history-evidence.com/myTutorials.txt

into a JSON array

As far as I know, I would have to first move it into a PHP array, and then translate to JSON.

I need to be a bit more clear about this I think,

must be JavaScript function

function executed returns a string

string is parsed as JSON, the result is an array containing IDs

This is what I got

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var filePath = "myTutorials.txt";
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET",filePath,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
var fileContent = xmlhttp.responseText;
var fileArray = fileContent.split('\n')

for (var i = 0, l = fileArray.length; i < l; ++i) {
fileArray[i] = fileArray[i].slice(0,7);
};

alert(fileArray.join('\n'));

</script>
```

Comment: It would involve first reading the file and regexing for spaces, I look forward for the answer, quite an interesting question :)

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in JavaScript or PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** since the question was edited and now is clear that a Javascript solution is needed, I updated the answer match the question. I kept the original PHP functions for reference.

Well, there's little json work involved here, most of the program will handle the string processing:

1. obtain the contents of that file via [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for examaple (or in PHP via [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php))
2. split the contents of the file in lines, you can use the [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method for this (or [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for PHP], this will generate an array filled with the lines from that file
3. iterate over the array from #2, and run another [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) (or [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)) to break each line into the fields, add the first field into the result array
4. encode the result array with [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (or [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for PHP)

Alternatively, you can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (or [array_map() in PHP](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)) at step #3 in order to reduce the complexity of your code.

Comment: oh yeah i like that

u think its possible to do without php ?

Comment: Im gonna try for a pure Javascript (no ajax / or php) solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$fh=fopen("samplie.txt","r");
if($fh){
    $arr=array();
    while(($line=fgets($fh))!=false){
        $arr[]=explode(" ",$line);
    }
    $temp=array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
        $temp[]=$arr[$i][0];
    }
    echo json_encode($temp);
}
```

This is one way but not the most efficient one.

Comment: This will generate a PHP warning if `$fh` is null (i.e. `fopen()` fails), as later on the code you try to access `$arr`, which would be undefined in this scenario.